# Windows batch file not working properly

Tags: windows, batch-file

My Batch file is not executing  the START serial_new.exe, it only terminates serial_new.exe.
it also opens and closes immediately.

```
ECHO OFF
c:
cd C:\wamp\www\mobilesms\
START serial_new.exe
echo testing echo..
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
taskkill /F /IM serial_new.exe
```

Comment: If `serial_new.exe` opens and closes, then it's being started.  It's not the `START` command's fault that `serial_new` exits right away.  however, if `serial_new.exe` is a console program, you might get a clue about what's wrong by using `START "" "cmd /k serial_new.exe"`

Comment: how can it terminate the exe if it isn't started first? that doesn't jibe.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`start "serial_new" serial_new.exe`
The start command needs a title for the first argument.

Comment: It only needs a title for the first argument if the first argument has quotes.  Rather, it always treats the first argument as a title if it has quotes.  Its command line parsing is unusual in this respect.